# Overriding third-party software GUI

Tags: windows, user-interface

Let say I have some third-party program installed on my computer with Windows 7 OS.

When I run it, I see the following:

[image]

I don't know anything about the program innards and all I want is to override it's GUI to display some extra information (red items on the next picture):

[image]

I guess it is possible, but I have no idea which way to dig.

Comment: That custom text would depend on the data from the application? Hardly possible, unless you have the source code or there is a plugin interface.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Yes, it should depend on the data from the application.

Comment: There is no reliable way of doing this without cooperation from the other application. Anything you come up with would be a hack that could stop working at any time. Make sure your customers understand this.

Comment: @RaymondChen In this case, I am the only customer, so that shouldn't be a problem. :) So I am interested in any guidance and hints.

Comment: For extracting text and detecting when the text changes, use the accessibility interfaces. (Assuming that the application supports them, which it will if it intends to sell to the U.S. government.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a [Windows Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I have made this a couple of times in the past to modify the behaviour of same third party applications. But that was a lot of years ago (Windows NT and Windows 95).